# Not sure how to turn this into a loop in python 3

Tags: python

Im very new to python and am a bit stuck. I have a variable called data that is json that I need to access. The problem is I get the json but it has values that end up changing due to the system processing payment information. I need to access the json after its been updated. Id like to run a loop that checks that variable.

code:

```
data = json.loads(self.rfile.read( length ).decode('utf-8'))
order_status = data['order_status']['name']

if not order_status == "Awaiting Payment":
    data = json.loads(self.rfile.read( length ).decode('utf-8'))
```

I want a loop that keeps checking order_status-> name and once its no longer saying "Awaiting Payment" set the data variable
Im not really sure how to do that

Answer (score 1):

```
import time

order_status = None

while not order_status == "Awaiting Payment":
    data = json.loads(self.rfile.read( length ).decode('utf-8'))
    order_status = data['order_status']['name']
    time.sleep(10) # sleep for 10 seconds

# do more stuff here
```